# User spamming - intentional or not?

Tags: discussion, users, hyperlinks, spam

I feel that a user is asking questions without the purpose of gaining an answer, but to rather link to several other sites. Multiple links in almost all of his / her questions with less then half of them with accepted answers.

I can't tell if he's simply being a good user with lots of links in his questions or someone who's asking lots of questions trying to increase site traffic.

Links:

From [Lazarus Form Recovery for Safari?](https://superuser.com/questions/109681/lazarus-form-recovery-for-safari)

> I use [Lazarus](http://lazarus.interclue.com/) a lot on Chrome and FireFox. Well, not a lot, but it's great for crashing when you're writing something online in a form that doesn't automatically save what you're writing. Plus, this should be default in every browser ANYway, and not built-in any web site (such as gmail).
>
> So, is there any such option for Safari?
> Does [Saft](http://haoli.dnsalias.com/Saft/) do that? Just by looking at the home page, it seems to me like bloatware to Safari 4.

From [Configuring 2 disks to run at same time on Time Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/109855/configuring-2-disks-to-run-at-same-time-on-time-machine)

> Ok, so rotating two disks with Time
> Machine is rather [simple](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090603163307642).
> Probably simpler than [using 3rd part
> to do backups (from this worth reading
> FAQ about TM)](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1964018#25) of it.
>
> I actually like to keep half my
> macbook's disk for TM and I want to
> add an external disk.
>
> Problem is: I can only choose one to
> backup on TM's settings.
>
> One possible solution is [setting up
> TM to a RAID](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showpost.php?p=512788&postcount=20), but I'm not sure
> this is a good idea, and I believe it
> would require both disks (or
> partitions) being the same size.
>
> Currently I think it's better to just
> manually rotate, by going to settings
> and changing the selected disk daily,
> or whatever frequency.
>
> I think the question here is: how can
> I do this automatically?

And more:

https://superuser.com/questions/109885/instant-email-alerts-and-notifications-closed

https://superuser.com/questions/110197/new-macbooks-touchpad-customizing-middle-clicks-and-few-swipe-actions-natively

[Keeping Mac OSX up and sleepless while task / app is running](https://superuser.com/questions/112027/keeping-mac-osx-up-and-sleepless-while-task-app-is-running)

[How could I safely fix my walking "dead pixel" bug?](https://superuser.com/questions/112921/how-could-i-safely-fix-my-walking-dead-pixel-bug)

[Backup Gmail using Mail.app and IMAP without redundancy](https://superuser.com/questions/114253/backup-gmail-using-mail-app-and-imap-without-redundancy)

[Real-Time chat translation on mac using either Skype, Adium or iChat](https://superuser.com/questions/116136/real-time-chat-translation-on-mac-using-either-skype-adium-or-ichat)

https://superuser.com/questions/116292/wheres-my-free-space-gone-on-my-mac-closed

[How to merge (and not replace) folders when copying on the Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/117621/how-to-merge-and-not-replace-folders-when-copying-on-mac)

[Old (Leopard) Expose on Snow Leopard (for mac)](https://superuser.com/questions/118424/old-leopard-expose-on-snow-leopard-for-mac)

https://superuser.com/questions/118463/no-reason-to-be-unable-to-mount-dmg-from-tuneup-and-no-errors-given-on-mac

[DMG mounting warning message says "it may make computer less secure or cause other problems"](https://superuser.com/questions/118487/dmg-mounting-warning-message-says-it-may-make-computer-less-secure-or-cause-othe)

Again, some of these look like legitimate questions, but for the most part it looks like a lot of links to other forums and boards, applications, and developer sites.

Comment: Perhaps he should be flagged, and let the mod decide.

Comment: Link or it didn't happen

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: (ie: point us to an example)

Comment: If you want us to give an informed opinion you'll have to give us a link to the maybe problematic questions.

Comment: If he doesn't own them, he could be paid to link to them.

Comment: @random: by *ALL* of them? I don't know if you took a look but there are really many different websites, some of them very known and reputable.

Comment: Today's link spammer knows that to make it look less like spamming certain sites, you have to throw in some in the clear to mix it up. @kop

Comment: Do you really mean 'spam' or do you mean 'rep whoring' ?

Comment: Wouldn't either be frowned upon?

Answer (score 5):

> Multiple links in almost all of his /
>   her questions with less then half of
>   them with accepted answers.
>
> I can't tell if he's simply being a
>   good user with lots of links in his
>   questions or someone who's asking lots
>   of questions trying to increase site
>   traffic.

Multiple links always to the same website or to different ones? In the former case it's probably spam, in the latter case he's just a linky person (yay I made up a new word)

**EDIT**: saw the links, come up how can that be spam? Do you think he owns all of those websites?

Comment: Multiple links to different web sites. I'm simply unsure.

Answer (score 3):

If you think it's spam, flag it as spam and the post will be automatically deleted (and the user will be hit with -100 to reputation) if five other users agree.

If you aren't sure, you can always flag anything for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like spam according to the regular definition of spam.  If we have spammers that are so clever as to actually ask useful and interesting questions in order to provide links, then by definition it's no longer spam.

In other words, as long as the content is topical and informative, the user's intentions are completely irrelevant.

Contrast:  Users who genuinely want help but ask for it in such a disjointed and ungrammatical way as to be incomprehensible have their questions closed.  We don't care whether they were *trying* to be coherent or not, all that matters is that they were incoherent.  The same applies in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything spammy about those links the majority seem to be pointing back to other similar, but not quite related enough questions. The next highest number are support forums for well known vendors that have no need to have someone spam for them (roxio and apple off the top of my head)

Also his listed website doesn't strike me as a spammer's at all.

To me it seems like someone who has done their research, gotten stuck, and included links to what they have already found.

Answer (score 1):

That is totally unacceptable behaviour. It would be like posting links to [Unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns) in totally non-[Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns) related answers.

It would be even worse if he used image links:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Seriously though, if there's a pattern, I would vote to close as Spam and maybe flag for moderator attention. If you're unsure, a question on Meta with links will give you feedback from the community, plus usually a moderator or two will see the issue straight away.